# How do I find a shell script that accepts one or more arguments, and outputs a line for each argument that names a UTF-8 file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I understand that I have to use an array of arguments, but have no experience doing so. I am using Emacs for my shell scripting.
This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash  
find $@ -type f -exec file {} + | grep UTF-8
```

Comment: `find` intended to search the contents of directories (and subdirectories and subsubdirectories etc). Do you really want to do that, or just check the files passed as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

answer because I can't comment yet:

`"$@"` and `"${name[@]}"` should always used with surrounding double quotes. Otherwise words with spaces are broken. See "man bash" for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to use $@ (every parameter), but I would solve your problem as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=($(find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep script | sed -r 's/([^:]*).*/\1/'))
for i in ${ARR[@]}; do
    if [ -x $i ]; then
        echo "$i is an executable script"
    fi
done
```

Find every file (including binaries), filter shell scripts with grep and take only take the file name with sed:

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep script | sed -r 's/([^:]*).*/\1/')
```

You can loop over the array items by using the "@" index. There are several others more which might be useful in the future:

```
for i in ${ARR[@]}; do
    #code
done
```

Finally, check if the script is executable with the -x option from [

```
if [ -x $i ]; then
    #do something
fi
```

p.s. isn't vim better than emacs? ;-)

Comment: Thank you! We use emacs because my professor literally helped code it lol.

Comment: Your welcome. It should be possible to remove "sed" and use the "-l" option from "grep", but I can't make it work. If the code doesn't work, check the output from "find" without grep and sed and change the grep pattern "script" accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: According to the description, it's supposed to check the files passed as arguments, not search the current directory (and its subdirectories). Also, you're using a bunch of techniques that'll fail on files with whitespace and/or wildcards in the names. See [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more robust ways to do this (if, indeed, that's what needs doing).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've interpreted the question differently. However, you're correct on the bug. I should have enclosed the $i variable with double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Just loop over the arguments with a `for`

```
#!/bin/bash  
for f in $@; do find -name "$f" -type f -exec file {} \; | grep UTF-8
```

Comment: Using `$*` and unquoted variable references (like `$f`) will cause trouble with filenames that contain whitespace and/or wildcards (which are both perfectly legal in unix filenames). Use `"$@"` and `"$f"` instead.